# BorderSide Color to BottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter

I want to add a colored BorderSide to the top of my BottomNavigationBar.

I can achieve it using a Custom BottomAppBar, but it is not convenient for my design as it misplaces my floatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked, so I need to stick with BottomNavigationBar.

Any help to find a workaround is appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomNavTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavTestState createState() => _BottomNavTestState();
}

class _BottomNavTestState extends State<BottomNavTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black, //
        currentIndex: 0,
        onTap: (index) {
          switch (index) {
            case 0:
              break;
            case 1:
              break;
          }
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
            title: Text('good'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_down),
            title: Text('bad'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Current output:

[image: Current Output]

My goal:

[image: My Goal]

Comment: Do you want a white horizontal line which shows in second image?

Comment: Yes, i wrote the image description but its not showing up

Comment: You can make that `BottomNavigationBar` as a `child` to the `Container`..I believe, you can give a `topBorder` to the `Container` on your own..

Comment: Anyway, you can add `topBorder` to `Container` like this..```decoration: BoxDecoration(
  border: Border(
    top: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.blue,
      // width: 3.0 --> you can set a custom width too!
    ),
  ),
),```..hope it solves your issue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it inside the container and give border

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2)
        ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.black, 
          currentIndex: 0,
          onTap: (index) {
            switch (index) {
              case 0:
                break;
              case 1:
                break;
            }
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
              title: Text('good'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_down),
              title: Text('bad'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: For some reason I remember getting some kind of error saying widget is not  subtype of type bottomNavigationBar, but it's working perfectly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make `BottomNavigationBar` as a child to the `Container`..

And add `topBorder` to `Container` like this..

```
decoration: BoxDecoration( border: Border( top: BorderSide( color: Colors.blue, // width: 3.0 --> you can set a custom width too! ), ), ),
```

hope it solves your issue